# comparing separate dataframes in python removing values

Tags: python, pandas, masking

I have two multi-index dataframes: `data1` and `data2` that I am running comparisons on.

Content of dataset `data1 =`

```
    Personalities   Rating
Type
        warm         5
Cat    caring        7
      frightful      9
       happy         3
```

Content of dataset `data2 =`

```
    Personalities   Rating
Type
          mean        3
Dog    ferocious      8
         loyal        4
         happy        1
          warm        6
```

I want to use a masking operation to identify all of the rows that do not have the same values in the personality column in both dataframes (all unique personality values).

Then, I need to remove all of those rows from the dataframe, so both dataframes will have the same values in their personalities columns.

My attempt consists in: `new_data1['Personalities'].isin(new_data2['Personalities']).any(axis=1)`

Result dataset of `new_data1 =`

```
    Personalities   Rating
Type
        warm         5
Cat    

       happy         3
```

Result dataset of `new_data2`

```
    Personalities   Rating
Type
          
Dog    

         happy        1
          warm        6
```

I'd like to create a new dataframe with the unique values where it would look something like this:
in `unique_data =`

```
Personalities   Rating
Type

Cat    caring        7
      frightful      9
Dog    mean          3
      ferocious      8
      loyal          4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input data:

```
>>> df1
     Personalities  Rating
Type
Cat           warm       5
Cat         caring       7
Cat      frightful       9
Cat          happy       3

>>> df2
     Personalities  Rating
Type
Dog           mean       3
Dog      ferocious       8
Dog          loyal       4
Dog          happy       1
Dog           warm       6
```

Prepare some sets:

```
s1 = set(df1["Personalities"])
s2 = set(df2["Personalities"])
```

Now, you can extract the data you need:

```
new_data1 = df1.loc[df1["Personalities"].isin(s1.intersection(s2))]

new_data2 = df2.loc[df2["Personalities"].isin(s2.intersection(s1))]

unique_data = pd.concat([df1.loc[df1["Personalities"].isin(s1.difference(s2))],
                         df2.loc[df2["Personalities"].isin(s2.difference(s1))]])
```

```
>>> new_data1
     Personalities  Rating
Type
Cat           warm       5
Cat          happy       3

>>> new_data2
     Personalities  Rating
Type
Dog          happy       1
Dog           warm       6

>>> unique_data
     Personalities  Rating
Type
Cat         caring       7
Cat      frightful       9
Dog           mean       3
Dog      ferocious       8
Dog          loyal       4
```